# In C++, what is the best way to allocate (and de-allocate) a very large array on a computer cluster?

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation

Why does the following code produce an error, and how do I fix it? I have been working on this for 2 days, so I would appreciate any advice. Basically, I do not know how to allocate and deallocate a very large array on a computer cluster with 200 GB of memory on a node. What are the best practices for this? Thank you!

```
const unsigned long int array_size_1 = 4032758016;
const unsigned long int array_size_2 = 2800526400;
const unsigned long int array_size_3 = 2800526400;
complex<double>* kinetic;
complex<double>* potential;
lapack_complex_double* hamiltonian;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {


    kinetic = new complex<double>[4032758016];
    potential = new complex<double>[4032758016];
    hamiltonian = new lapack_complex_double[4032758016];

    delete[] kinetic;
    delete[] potential;
    delete[] hamiltonian;
}
```

The code compiles. But during run-time...
Error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221602/discussion-on-question-by-christina-daniel-in-c-what-is-the-best-way-to-alloc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you *actually* need the contiguous array of this size. The solution is `std::deque`: this looks very similar to `std::vector`, but the elements are stored in chunks. The random access is constant, `push_back` is even faster than the vector's.

This container is used for two major purposes: whenever you need a queue with push/pop operations on both sides, and for the purpose of storing extremely large buffers.

The code would look like:

```
#include <deque>

const unsigned long int array_size_1 = 4032758016;
const unsigned long int array_size_2 = 2800526400;
const unsigned long int array_size_3 = 2800526400;
std::deque<complex<double>> kinetic;
std::deque<complex<double>> potential;
std::deque<lapack_complex_double> hamiltonian;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    kinetic.resize(array_size_1);
    potential.resize(array_size_2);
    hamiltonian.resize(array_size_3);
}
```